# iOS 8 NSTimer issue

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I've run in to a strange problem on iOS8. The app I'm working has been around a long time and works just fine on iOS6 and 7. Well, at least this part of the code :-).

The problem is a count down timer which is started by a call from viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)startCountdownTimer {
    if(self.countdownTimer!=nil)
        [self stopCountdownTimer];
    self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self 
      selector:@selector(countdownTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.countdownStartTime = [NSDate date];
}
```

In countdownTick the remaining time is checked and when you're down to 0 a UIAlertView is shown.

```
- (void)countdownTick {    
    NSTimeInterval remainingTime = [self remainingCountdownTimerTime];
    self.timeLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f s", remainingTime];
    if(remainingTime==0) {
        [self stopCountdownTimer];
        [self showCountdownTimerRestartRequest];
    }
}
```

And finally stopCountdownTimer is called from viewWillDisappear

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self stopCountdownTimer];
}
- (void)stopCountdownTimer {
    [self.countdownTimer invalidate];
    self.countdownTimer = nil;
}
```

No rocket science.

This works as expected in iOS6 and iOS7 but for some strange reason not in iOS8. On iOS 8 the timer still keeps running even after leaving the viewController. So the alertView will appear in completely the wrong place. I've added some logging and the timer is stopped and set to nil. Still the alert appears 90 seconds (the timer interval) after the timer was started.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: does it keep showing up after leaving or just once?

Comment: bad.. looks like a bug

Comment: It will keep showing up until I kill the app

Comment: try invalidating the instance variable instead of property, secondly check timer is created and invalidated on one thread

Comment: I just tested the above code works fine in iOS 8. So, I suspect it's either a question of how you're "leaving" the view controller (i.e. `viewWillDisappear` is not getting called) or you have some other timer lingering about. I'd suggest creating a reproducible example of this problem from scratch and you'll generally find precisely which step in the process manifests the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. ViewWillDisapear is being called and the last thing I do is log that the timer object is invalidated and set to nil. I'll follow your suggestion, Rob and try it out in a dummy-app. Also I'll look in to the invalidating the instance variables instad. The weird thing is that the code in the app works on iOS7. I'm confused.